# How to release the Video File of WM ASF Writer

Tags: c#, directshow, directshow.net

I use  this code to create, and add an asf Writer to my graph

```
IFileSinkFilter pTmpSink = null;
IBaseFilter asfWriter = null;
int hr = capGraph.SetOutputFileName( MediaSubType.Asf, szOutputFileName,
 out asfWriter, out pTmpSink);
```

i want to stop saving the video capturing, release the video file, and then rerun the graph so that preview continue.

```
m_mediaCtrl.Stop();
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(asfWriter);
m_mediaCtrl.Run();
```

the problem is that when i Release asfWriter, the file didn't receive the video capturing, and it's size is always 5.08KB. if i didn't release the asfWriter the file receives the video stream (also not running the graph again)

i appreciate any help, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the solution is to disconnect the asfWriter from the graph and then remove it.
in my case it's connected the the pin 0 of a SmartTee. hope this helps someone else.

```
m_mediaCtrl.Stop();
if(asfWriter != null)
{
      IPin pin = DsFindPin.ByDirection(iSmartTee, PinDirection.Output, 0);
      hr = m_FilterGraph.Disconnect(pin);
      hr = m_FilterGraph.RemoveFilter(asfWriter); 
}
m_mediaCtrl.Run();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't just remove filters from a DirectShow graph without stopping the whole graph. Just stopping and running again the media control filter isn't enough. You even can't change the pin connections while the graph is running.

So if you want to stop capturing to a file while seamlessly continuing live preview, there are two options I can suggest:

- Create your own `AsfWriter` using the Windows Media SDK. That isn't that hard but you definitely will spend some time reading docs and implementing that stuff. Your custom `AsfWriter` could then have a routine that stops encoding, finalizes the file and tells the filter to just drop all further incoming samples. I've created such a custom `AsfWriter` that can encode video in a ring-buffer.
- Another option could be to create three graphs (capturing, live view, live view plus encoding) and connect them via [GMFBridge](http://www.gdcl.co.uk/gmfbridge/). You need to do some multithreading stuff there anyway.

If you're okay with stopping the graph, then you can create two independent graphs: one that captures and shows preview, the other one only for previewing. So after stopping the first graph, start the second.